# Plotting Implicit Function using Sympy

Tags: python, arrays, plot, sympy, equation

I am trying to plot the function
I tried to plot (`n_eff vs ka` - `y` and `x` respectively in my example) it by using the `plot_implicit()` function of sympy but it is taking too much time probably because of function being too complicated.

[image: check here]

I thought of another method to solve it by using solve function of sympy for different values of `x`. i.e., make an array for `x` and use values of that array to find `y` and then plot. I am new to sympy so I dont know how to do that. Any help is appreciated
Assume that values of `n1, n2 and n3` are known and are just numbers

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import var, plot_implicit
import sympy
var('x y')
n1 = 2
n2 = 2.2
n3 = 2.1
U = x*(n1**2 + y)**(1/2)
W2 = x*(y**2 - n2**2)**(1/2)
W3 = x*(y**2 - n3**2)**(1/2)
f = sympy.tanh(2*U) - n1**2*U*(n3**2*W2 + n2**2*W3)/(n2**2*n3**2*U**2 + n1**4*W2*W3)
plot_implicit(f)
```

Comment: Could you add the Python code you used for your function? Together with some typical values for the variables?

Comment: @JohanC Check it now. I have replaced 'ka' with x and 'neff' with y

Comment: you can make subscript names with an underscore just as they do in the example, which I think would be better (however, I've cleaned up your other vars intermediately) .. you may find plotting over some numpy.linspace works better

Comment: What are the desired ranges for x and y? Maybe strange things happen when trying to take square roots of negative values?

Comment: @JohanC Desired range for x is 0.005 to 0.2 and for y it is all real values

Comment: @JohanC https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTp7G.png Check this link. I am trying to reproduce this plot

Comment: You could experiment with the parameters.  E.g. `plot_implicit(f, (x, 0.0005, 0.2), (y, 0, 9), adaptive=False)`